# How to upload a file to a specific location in the local machine using HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, download

I am new to javascript, one of my use case is to upload a file from my local computer to a selected directory in same computer.

HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h3>File Upload to the selected location</h3>
      <form action="">
         <input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple />
         <output id="list"></output>
      </form>
      <script src="testing.js"></script>
      <br><br> Local Path (C:\Users\UserName\Documents\) <input type="checkbox" value="TestPurpose">
   </body>
</html>
```

JS Code:

```
function handleFileSelect(evt) {
    var files = evt.target.files; // FileList object
    // files is a FileList of File objects. List some properties.
    var output = [];
    for (var i = 0, f; f = files[i]; i++) {
        output.push('<li><strong>', escape(f.name), '</strong> (', f.type || 'n/a', ') - ',
            f.size, ' bytes, last modified: ',
            f.lastModifiedDate ? f.lastModifiedDate.toLocaleDateString() : 'n/a',
            '</li>');
    }
    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = '<ul>' + output.join('') + '</ul>';
}
document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

so once i upload a file from my local machine and select the checkbox, the uploaded file should move to the specified location besides the html checkbox. 
can someone please help me with this?

Comment: You don't access user's local system, user selects the saving folder himself.

Comment: so may i know how can i store the uploaded file in the same local computer?

Comment: I repeat, you can't access user's local system, hence you can't store any files on user's system either ... I suppose that with "uploaded file" you mean the file user has picked up with `#files`. The only way is to send it to you server, and then load it back to user, when they can save it to their local system. JS/browser is not purposed for disk operations, use OS to save/copy/rename or what ever your files.

Comment: yes, so in my further use cases, uploaded files need to be sent to some remote server , but then i need to be able to select the location of the files being stored in remote server, its more like i need select file location of remote server from UI and upload my files there.

Comment: I wouldn't let arbitrary visitors to decide where and what they save into my server ... Wait! You actually just want to show the path of the file next to a checkbox? Well, not possible either, you can only get a fake path from `#files`.

Comment: Yes, i just want show the path of the file next to a checkbox and once i upload files,  the file should actually get uploaded and be available in the remote server at the specified path(which will be known to me). but that's the future case. for now i was just testing if i could upload on same computer. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security reasons you do not have access to user's file system. The file can only be downloaded as a result of direct interaction from user (confirming download) and only in directory selected by user either during every specific download manually or in default download directory (depends on browser settings).